# Crystal Reports on click get content

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am using visual studio 2015 and crystal reports 2013 (version 14.1.4.1327). On crystalReportViewer when I click a TextObject, or anything else on the report, is there a way to get the section name or the value of the clicked content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void crystalReportViewer1_ClickPage(object sender, CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageMouseEventArgs e)
            {
                // Collect the report object name and type.
                string msg = "Report Object: " + e.ObjectInfo.Name.ToString()
                    + " (" + e.ObjectInfo.ObjectType.ToString() + ")";

                // Some report objects won't have text properties; verify that the property isn't null 
                // before attempting to access it.
                if (e.ObjectInfo.Text != null)
                {
                    msg += "... Text: " + e.ObjectInfo.Text.ToString();
                }

                // Display the collected information in a message box.
                MessageBox.Show(msg);
            }
```

Found the answer here: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1073492

However, this won't work for subreports.